# What enables the SXA style and behavior editing of a component?

Tags: sxa

I am trying to minimum requirements for enabling styling and behavior editing on a SXA component (using SXA 1.8).

At the moment I have a `Controller` that inherits from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Controllers.StandardController` and a MVC View with the following CSS classes:

```
<div class="component content col12">
    <div class="component-content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

NB. in production I of course want to use the Razor functions to add the CSS classes, but having same like this makes it for now more explicit.

With my current setup I do not see the "Edit style and behavior" button appearing the Experience Editor. What do I miss?

Comment: Does your component have rendering parameters that inherit from IStyling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the template used as **Parameters Template** should have the  `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Grid/Rendering Parameters/Grid Parameters` template associated.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller rendering you have a field called **Parameters Template**, in there point to the template "/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Presentation/Rendering Parameters/IStyling"

Note: If you have this field filled with a template of you own just inherit your template from IStyling template.

Now your rendering should have "Edit style and behavior".

Comment: Added the IStyling as Parameters Template but doesn't solve it.